# What is the make and model of my bike? The serial number is WW025278. I've been searching for a week. I think it's a katakura silk

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

[image: head badge i found online for a katakura silk jr enter image description hereelectron winker][image]The head badge looks almost similar to a old school Cadillac symbol and it says silk. One number on the bike is ww025278. And another small number that starts off with a weird [looking[image: ][1]] peace sign with 6397.

[image]

Comment: Also compare to existing photos at https://www.tracksupermarket.com/katakura-silk-red-cm-track-frame.html

Comment: The serial number is useless unless you already know the manufacturer.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. It is nearly impossible to identify a bicycle without pictures. There's no centralized database for serial numbers. Please [edit] some into your question. Once you do so, the question will automatically be flagged for reopening. You can find out more about how our site works by taking our [tour]. Also, please don't take the downvotes too harshly. They're just a reflection of the need for pictures. Once your question is edited and reopened, it'll likely garner more upvotes from the community.

Comment: How's that. Thank you for the help..

Comment: I can't find that head badge anywhere.

Comment: @JulianA great work - thank you.  Question is reopened.

Comment: Yea I finally found it. Check this out

Answer (score 2):

Straight up - that bike frame has been in a frontal collision which may explain why it was stripped of most other parts.

Notice the fork's tines/legs are bent backward. I wonder if a normal 700c wheel+tyre risks touching the downtube.

Check for

- paint rub on the underside of the downtube where the tyre has touched the frame
- cracks and rust in the head tube and downtube at a point 2-4 inches aft of the headtube
- bearing seats in the headset (just turn the bars and feel for bad bearings is easiest)

If the forks are steel they might be straightened, but there's risk of weakening them too.  A professional would heat them carefully, controlling the temperature and temper of the metal, at a cost.

Of course if you only intend for this to be wall art, that doesn't matter.  If you intend on riding it, this history needs to be considered and the risks evaluated.

A replacement threaded fork is also a possibility for added confidence.